# OBIEE 11g Users are not visible in Identity Manager within Administration Tool which are created in Weblogic

Tags: obiee

OBIEE 11g Users are not visible in Identity Manager within Administration Tool which are created in Weblogic.

Login The Oracle WebLogic Server Administration Console. In the Security Realms Create user and assign them Groups BIAuthors, BIAdministrator and BIConsumers .

Open BI Administration Application. Open an offline repository. Go to Manage->Identity. All users which are created should be displayed over there but only weblogic user is displayed there.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open the BI Administration Tool and open the repository in online mode.
2. Open the Identity Manager from Manage menu and check the list of the existing
   users. You'll only see the weblogic user account.
3. Click on the Set Online User Filter... option from the Action menu.
4. Enter * as a wild character to import all user identities.

You'll see all the user accounts.